# How can I effectively summarize and visualize time series of employee activities?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

I am managing many people entering data into a database. I have a log of user, date, time, table, and action that each person makes:

```
records <- data.frame(user = c('bob', 'bob', 'jane', 'jane', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'jane', 'jane', 'bob'),
                      date = c("2010-06-24", "2010-06-28", "2010-06-29", "2010-06-30", "2010-07-01", "2010-07-02", "2010-07-05", "2010-07-06", "2010-07-07", "2010-07-09"), 
                      time = c("01:40:08", "01:40:18", "01:40:28", "01:40:37", "01:40:44", "01:40:52", "01:40:59", "01:56:26", "02:16:37", "03:55:06"),
                      table = c(rep('table1',5), rep('table2',5)),
                      action = c('create', 'create', 'create', 'update', 'create', 'update', 'update', 'create', 'create', 'create'))
```

For a non-trivial example, the actual `records` dataframe with 10,000 entries can be downloaded as an .Rdata file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18092793/records.Rdata), and then:

```
load('records.Rdata')
library(ggplot2)
qplot(date, table, data = records, color = user, geom='jitter')
```

How can I visualize, overall and for each table:

1. the amount of time each person works per week
2. the type and number or frequency of actions that they made.

?

Comment: @David this is not just a visualization problem, you may be interested in the discussion of split-apply-combine strategies facilitated by Hadley's plyr package http://had.co.nz/plyr/plyr-intro-090510.pdf

Comment: @David how do you compute the "amount"? Is it the sum of actions? We would need the duration of each single action if you want the amount of time...

Comment: @teucer I was thinking about the number of create/update/check actions entered per unit time for each table between the first login and last action. Some tables might have 1-2 creates/week, while others may have as many as 100 creates in a day or even more checks/day.

Comment: @David could you provide the duration of each logging?

Comment: @David I guess when you say first login and last action, these are per day(?). I can easily compute the number of actions per user per week, but, with the given data, it is difficult to translate this in amount of time...

Comment: @teucer, each logging event is instantaneous, but the employees are assumed to be working on the next logging event between one logging and the next. To a first approximation, for each day x user combination, the amount of total time worked could be estimated as the max(time) - min(time) + 30 min, and a continuous block of time could be considered any stretch of time during which $max(\Delta t)<30\text{min}$.

Comment: @teucer I do have a separate time sheet, so that would probably be a good estimate of the total time spent, so really the number of actions per day or per week are more important.

Answer (score 2):

Below the code to plot the numbers of actions per week/per user:

```
load("records.Rdata")
library(ggplot2)
records$posdate <- as.POSIXlt(records$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
records$week <- as.numeric(format(records$posdate,"%W")) #changed from previous hack!
numberActions <- by(records$action,records[,c("user","week")],function(x) length(x[x!="Login"]))
numberActions <- melt(t(numberActions[1:7,]),"week")
colnames(numberActions)[2] <- "user"
ggplot(numberActions,aes(week,value,group=user,col=user))+geom_line()+geom_point(size=3)
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

For the second part you can use `plyr`:

```
numberActions <- ddply(records,c("user","week"),function(x) table(x$action))
numberActions <- melt(numberActions,c("user","week"))
numberActions <- numberActions[numberActions$value!=0 & numberActions$variable!="Login",]
```

and then the usual `ggplot`...

Comment: thanks for walking me through the data manipulation, but how can I retain the variables 'action' and 'table' so that I can use something like `facet_grid(. ~ action)` or `facet_grid(. ~ action*table)`?

Comment: @David, `rr <-records[records$action!="Login",]`
`ddply(rr,~user+table+action+week,nrow)`